# Get dict values based on a filtered list with a varying number of returned elements

Tags: python-3.x

I am filtering elements from a list that include `'"'` by the following code:

```
def sizes():
    new_list = [x for x in mid_item_size_one if '"' in x]
    return new_list
```

This will return any element with `'"'` as desired. Example strings below.

```
Random Text 0.5" Random Text
0.25" Random Text
1.5" x 0.5" Random Text
```

I `.split` then apply above function to return:

```
['0.5"']
['0.25"']
['1.5"', '0.5"']
```

I now need to lookup each of the elements in a dictionary and return the value from the key:value pair as new individual variables so I will be able to add them to a new string that contains a number of other variables. See example of desired Result below:

```
val_1 = '0.5"'
val_1 = '0.5"'
val_1 = '1.5"' and val_2 = '0.5"'
```

```
Random Text val_1 Random Text
Random Text val_1 Random Text
Random Text val_1 Random Text val_2
```

I already have my function to lookup/retrieve the value from dictionary however since I started retrieving the values via filter, I haven't been able to figure out how to retrieve the dict value.

```
def item_size_one_final(size_dict):
    for x in sizes():
        for key in size_dict:
            if key in sizes():
                return size_dict[key]
        return "Hmmmm"
    return"Not Working"
```

The above for loops result in `['Hmmmm']` on all of it. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to do this?

@Riedler - Sure, hopefully this example helps.

```
size_dict = {
    '1/4"' : '8mm - 1/4"',
    '1.5"' : '40mm - 11/2"',
    '0.5"' : '15mm - 1/2"',}
```

Raw Data Input:

```
0.5" Pipe
1/4" Flange
1.5" x 0.5" Reducer
```

My company uses SAP with set item codes and item description formats so I am taking those three descriptions and putting them in our format. This:

```
def sizes():
    new_list = [x for x in mid_item_size_one if '"' in x]
    return new_list
```

add a step in between to split into a list then this is returned:

```
['0.5"']
['0.25"']
['1.5"', '0.5"']
```

From this point, I need to run these elements through my dictionary and get the value (key:**value** pair). My current for loop doesn't work and I'm not sure why or what I can alter to correct it.
The final result should be:

```
var_1 = 15mm - 1/2"
var_1 = 8mm - 1/4"
var_1 = 40mm - 11/2", var_2 = 15mm - 1/2"
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you want the code to do. Can you please provide more specific input- and output values? Thanks.

Comment: @Riedler - I've edited my OP to include a 2nd example that is hopefully clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your mistake is that you are cycling over the dictionary for every value in the list of sizes, why?

The idea of a dictionary is that when you have a value that matches a key, you can get the matching value from the dictionary.

Also, there is no need to call `sizes` twice to receive the same values, save the result before and then use that.

```
def item_size_one_final(size_dict):
    sizes_lst = sizes()
    res = []
    for x in sizes_lst:
        if x in size_dict:
            res.append(size_dict[x])
    return res
```

Comment: Booby Trap - That returns the error ```KeyError: '0.5"'``` on the return. My sizes funct gives me all sizes in the string because I work with products that will sometimes have multiple sizes and, when this occurs, I need the dict value for each of the sizes in that item. Is that what you're asking? Added snipit to OP to show you it is in the dictionary.

Comment: @Blackmagic42 Ah, sorry. Messed that one up in the `if` condition. It should have been `size_dict` and not `sizes_lst`. Your keys in your `size_dict` are the problem, remove the commas from there, they aren't needed.
I'll update my answer as I think I know better what you mean now.

Comment: Booby Trap - I noticed the comma too - those are from a previous attempt to extract the sizes but yeah, time to remove them. That gets it to generate the value for the items with 1 size however the items with 2 sizes only returns the 1 value. I wonder if the best way after that would be to delete that first size from string and have it process again?

Comment: @Blackmagic42
I have updated the answer to return a list, so now you should be getting a list in the size of the matching sizes. In a way that the first value will match the first key in sizes and so on.

Comment: Nice - that gets the list of items. Thank you!